# Saving a VM instance in google cloud compute

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I believe this is what's happening. Can someone tell me for sure:

When I have a vm running a webserver I am charged for time I leave the vm running if I give it a static IP.

If I dont give a webserver a static IP I am charged for only the machine time I spend SSH'ed into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be charge for the time that the i[nstance will be running.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#instanceuptime) If you have an [static IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#ipaddress) assigned but unused you will be charge, but not if is ephemeral or the static IP is unused. You can use the [Google Cloud Platform pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/) to get estimate your cost. You also need to consider the price for [persistence disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#persistentdisk).